# Gulp is not copying any html files in the build cmmand

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-concat

gulp build command is copying and minifying all the JS and CSS files from my app folder into dist/ folder, but it is not copying any html Files into the dist folder.

I am using ng-route from angular . 
Here is the code from my routes.js file :

```
module1.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/app/pages/home.html',
                controller: 'mainController',
                resolve: {
                    resolvedJSON: function (UserService) {
                        return UserService.getModelTable1();
                    }
```

});

Can someone help me as to why Gulp is not picking the html files during build?

My Gulpfile.js is :

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const HubRegistry = require('gulp-hub');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync');

const conf = require('./conf/gulp.conf');


// Load some files into the registry
const hub = new HubRegistry([conf.path.tasks('*.js')]);

// Tell gulp to use the tasks just loaded
gulp.registry(hub);

gulp.task('inject', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('styles', 'scripts'), 'inject'));
gulp.task('build', gulp.series('partials', gulp.parallel('inject', 'other'), 'build'));
gulp.task('test', gulp.series('scripts', 'karma:single-run'));
gulp.task('test:auto', gulp.series('watch', 'karma:auto-run'));
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('inject', 'watch', 'browsersync'));
gulp.task('serve:dist', gulp.series('default', 'browsersync:dist'));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'build'));
gulp.task('watch', watch);


/*
// JS hint task
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
  gulp.src('./src/scripts/*.js')
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'));
});
*/

// minify new images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  var imgSrc = './src/images/**/*',
      imgDst = './build/images';

  gulp.src(imgSrc)
    .pipe(changed(imgDst))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDst));
});
function reloadBrowserSync(cb) {
  browserSync.reload();
  cb();
}

function watch(done) {
  gulp.watch([
    conf.path.src('index.html'),
    'bower.json'
  ], gulp.parallel('inject'));

  gulp.watch(conf.path.src('app/**/*.html'), reloadBrowserSync);
  gulp.watch([
    conf.path.src('**/*.css')
  ], gulp.series('styles'));
  gulp.watch(conf.path.src('**/*.js'), gulp.series('inject'));
  done();
}
```

My build.js file is as below:

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const filter = require('gulp-filter');
const useref = require('gulp-useref');
const rev = require('gulp-rev');
const revReplace = require('gulp-rev-replace');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const uglifySaveLicense = require('uglify-save-license');
const inject = require('gulp-inject');
const ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');

var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

const conf = require('../conf/gulp.conf');

gulp.task('build', build);

// minify new images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  var imgSrc = './src/images/**/*',
      imgDst = './build/images';

  gulp.src(imgSrc)
    .pipe(changed(imgDst))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(imgDst));
});

function build() {
  const partialsInjectFile = gulp.src(conf.path.tmp('templateCacheHtml.js'), {read: false});
  const partialsInjectOptions = {
    starttag: '<!-- inject:partials -->',
    ignorePath: conf.paths.tmp,
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  const htmlFilter = filter(conf.path.tmp('**/*.html'), {restore: true});
  const jsFilter = filter(conf.path.tmp('**/*.js'), {restore: true});
  const cssFilter = filter(conf.path.tmp('**/*.css'), {restore: true});

  return gulp.src(conf.path.tmp('/index.html'))
    .pipe(inject(partialsInjectFile, partialsInjectOptions))
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify({preserveComments: uglifySaveLicense})).on('error', conf.errorHandler('Uglify'))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore)
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore)
    .pipe(revReplace())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe(htmlmin())
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(conf.path.dist()));
}
```

Comment: perhaps you should post your gulpfile.js source instead. your route.js has nothing to do with that

Comment: Not sure what your Angular code has to do with gulp.  Can you post your gulp code here?  That's probably the source of the problem.

Comment: @Dr.Cool  I have posted my gulpfile.js and build.js file from gulp tasks for your reference.

Comment: @doge1ord...I have attached the gulpfile.js and build.js file from gulp tasks for your reference.